# Why compiler couldn't match type 'a==a' with '`True' for type family?

Tags: haskell, type-families, data-kinds

Is there some reason why this code is not compiled:

```hs
type family Foo a b :: Bool where
    Foo a b = a == b

foo :: Foo a b ~ True => Proxy a -> Proxy b
foo _ = Proxy

bar :: Proxy a -> Proxy a
bar = foo
```

with error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a == a’ with ‘'True’
Expected type: 'True
  Actual type: Foo a a
```

but if I change type family definition to

```hs
type family Foo a b :: Bool where
    Foo a a = True
    Foo a b = False
```

it is compiled well?

(ghc-7.10.3)

Comment: Where is the type family `==` defined? Is it lifted from instances automatically by GHC? If so, GHC has to account for the possibility of a weird instance where on some custom type `(==) = \_ _ -> False`, I guess.

Comment: Can you include a complete working example? When I try your example, I get different errors than the one you showed.

Comment: @chi, or not weird: `(let x = 0/0 in x == x) ~> False`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Due to a request for a complete working example from Daniel Wagner, I found an answer.

Complete example at first:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
module Test where

import Data.Type.Equality(type (==))
import Data.Proxy(Proxy(..))

type family Foo a b :: Bool where
    Foo a b = a == b

foo :: Foo a b ~ True => Proxy a -> Proxy b
foo _ = Proxy

bar :: Proxy a -> Proxy a
bar = foo
```

The problem here is with `PolyKinds` pragma. Without it it works well.
I probably need it so that I can write

```
bar :: Proxy (a :: *) -> Proxy a
```

and all goes well.

The reason is clear now. The type family (`==`) has no poly-kinded instances (details explaining why such instances aren't provided [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/src/Data.Type.Equality.html#line-130)) so we can't reduce all equalities. So we need to specify a kind.

Comment: @haoformayor When quoting content from outside sources you should use blockquotes, so that it's clear what was quoted. In this specific case the formatting was terrible and would require some treatment. Also the content you edited in is *not* essential to answer the question and as such there's no need to actually copy it. The answer is already complete without it, the "why" no polykinded instance is provided can be answered in an other question or just left as a link for *further* reading.

Comment: What is the utility of your `==` type family? It's usually much easier to work with native type equality (`~`) than it is to build a Boolean equality into the type system. At the end of the day you have to use `~` to do anything with the result of `==`, as you did in `foo`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson: `==` is not mine. It is from the `base` package. It is a type family which result has kind `Bool`. On the other hand, result of `~` has kind `Constraint`. So `==` is usable in boolean type level calculation. You can't use `~` instead there.

Comment: My question is really _why are you using Boolean equality and not [propositional equality](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html#t::-126-:)_?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson _propositional equality_ (`:~:`) is a data type with kind `*`. I can't see how to use it instead of type family `==` in type calculation. It seems too common question about all these equalities for comments. Probably better to ask it separately?